# SELECT and MATCH performance

Tags: performance, match, orientdb

As the title, I have a query as below

```
SELECT * FROM (
    MATCH....
    RETURN...
)
```

This query takes about 20 seconds to finish.

But if I run MATCH...RETURN... only, it only takes about 0.05 seconds

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: How many records are returned by the query?

Comment: @AlessandroRota Only 2 records

Comment: Which version are you using ? What type of property do you have in your records?

Comment: @AlessandroRota I found a critical issue of MATCH command.
I will report in soon on Github and notify you later.

Comment: Hi @AlessandroRota, I just created an issue [#6826](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6826). Please help check.